# R: Using source and loop cycle to run a 2nd script

Tags: r, loops

I am using command source in a Script (Script Number 1) to run other script file saved (Script number 2).

My idea is use a loop to read continually the Script number 2 that is modified continually. I Never stop the loop. But Lamentably this dont work.

Always Script number 1 read the original Script number 2 and not change the result when I change the script number 2. I am using a sublime Text to change the script and not stop the loop cycle.

Example:

Example Script number 1:

```
    repeat{

    source("C:/Users/myPC/Desktop/script.R")
    Sys.sleep(10) 

    }
```

Example Script number 2 modified (script saved as script.R in my desktop):

```
repeat {
  print('Checking files')

  Sys.sleep(time=10)  

}
```

This run ok. But during the loop cycle I make changes to the script number 2 (and save file) :

Script number 2 modified:

```
repeat {
  print('NOW RE-Checking files')

  Sys.sleep(time=10)  

}
```

The result always is this. Not read the script number 2 modified.

```
[1] "Checking files"
[1] "Checking files"
[1] "Checking files"
[1] "Checking files"
[1] "Checking files"
[1] "Checking files"
```

Comment: (1) If the other script is being modified in-place, then when you read/source it, you have no guarantee that the writing process is done writing it, and it is risky/dangerous to assume otherwise. You are not (yet) seeing this problem, but I find it highly unlikely that it will never happen. (2) Your script-1 `repeat` loop never repeats: on the first call to `source(.)`, it yields control to the `repeat` loop of script-2 that never ends.

Comment: This seems like a very odd way to solve something. I suggest it might be helpful if you explain why you think having two `repeat` (forever) loops in two scripts is the best or only way to resolve your problem.

Comment: Some conditions/environments change. My idea is not stop the loop to modified the script-2.  I use this example to not stop the loop script2  and run again the script.

Comment: My idea to use repeat in script-1 is to get the changes in script-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing what your scripts are really doing, it's a little guess-work, but I'll work on the two things I do know from this:

1. Checking to see if a file has been changed and then reloading it will work 95-99% or more of the time. Unfortunately, the risk is that whatever is *writing* the file will still be writing when your script-1 tries to `source` it: writing contents to a file is never atomic, so you cannot guarantee without some form of file-lock (not supported on all filesystems) or other coordination mechanism.

   To remedy this, I suggest that what mechanism (sight-unseen) that is modifying script-2 needs to write to a temp-file and then destructively rename it to be `script2.R`. While writing to a file is not atomic, renaming/moving a file *is atomic*. With this, when `script1.R` notices that a file has been updated, it will get to read the whole thing unabated.
2. I suggest that instead of *running code* in `script2.R`, you should define a function that is called (repeatedly) by script-1. That way, script-1 retains control and can check for updates in `script2.R` and, as necessary, reload it. The function one writes in script-2 needs to do one thing and then yield control back to the caller; that is, no `repeat` or `while` loops unless they are very well contained/limited and will not take longer to exit than you expect `script2.R` to be updated. (Recognize that script-2's while/repeat loop will not be interrupted, so plan accordingly.)

   (`script2.R`)

   ```r
   work <- function() {
     print("Checking files")
     Sys.sleep(10)
   }
   ```

   (`script1.R`)

   ```r
   prevmt <- NA
   repeat {
     mt <- file.info("script2.R")$mtime
     if (is.na(prevmt) || prevmt < mt) {
       source("script2.R")
     }
     work()
     Sys.sleep(10)
   }
   ```